# How to start a MATLAB console and input commands to it?

Tags: linux, bash, matlab

I'm designing a script where I run matlab and prompt commands to it. However, as I actually start matlab to run and then quit, script is quite slow.

I wonder what's my alternative if I want to start a matlab console, and prompt inputs to such pid, they way I can get results faster.

This is an example of how I invoke matlab

```
sudo matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -nojvm -r "syms x; x=4; disp(4+5*x); exit"
```

I'm using Ubuntu Linux, so of course it's a bash console.

Answer (score 2):

Quick search appears to use the -nodesktop flag.

http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/02/22/launching-matlab-without-the-desktop/

If you are wanting to run a script using that line, you would include the -r  where  is the name of the script WITHOUT the .m.

http://lembra.wordpress.com/2010/08/17/running-a-matlab-script-misleading-m/

Comment: I'm already doing that, but still I get an almost 3 seconds lag as MATLAB is actually invoked from 0.

Comment: I believe that is just how matlab works.  I've always had some degree of difficulty in running matlab from command line, to the point of having to force delays in dependent scripts in order to give matlab time to run a small amount of code.